holomorphic $f$ with $f(a_k)=0$ implies $f=0$
This is problem 8 in a previous Texas qualifier:

Let $f:D\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be a holomorphic bounded function. Prove that if there is a sequence of distinct points $a_k$ such that $f(a_k)=0$ and $\sum_{k=1}^\infty (1-|a_k|)=\infty$, then $f\equiv 0$.

I thought this would be a simple consequence of the Identity Theorem, but it turns out it is not. My first try went like this:
First try:
If there is a subsequence such that $|a_{k_j}|\leq r<1$, we are done, as there is a sub-subsequence converging to a point $z_o$ which is a zero. Suppose there is no such $r$. This means that only finitely many $a_k$ satisfy $|a_k|\leq 1-\frac{1}{n^2}$.  Let $B_n$ denote the indices of the elements which satisfy this. Define $A_n=B_{n+1}\setminus B_n$ such that if $k\in A_n$, then  $1-\frac{1}{n^2}<|a_k|\leq 1-\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}$. Remove any $a_k=0$ from our sequence so that $\mathbb{N}=\dot{\cup} A_n$. We have that because we have a sum of positive terms it is commutatively convergent and:
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty (1-|a_k|)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{k\in A_n} (1-|a_k|)<\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{k\in A_n}\frac{1}{n^2}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{|A_n|}{n^2}$$
One cannot draw any contradiction out of this as $|A_n|$ is finite but could be very large. In any case we can easily build a sequence of real $a_k$ converging to $1$ such that $|A_n|=n+1$ and in this case
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{k\in A_n} (1-|a_k|)\geq \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{k\in A_n}\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}=\infty$$
So it is not true one can always find a subsequence in $D_r=\{z\:|\:|z|\leq r<1\}$, which shatters any hope that the Identity Theorem can be useful. :(
Second try: Because the Identity Theorem didn't seem to work, I remembered I used Blaschke factors to estimate a function in the unit disk before. An argument similar to the one in the hyperlink teaches me that if $|f(z)|\leq M$, then:
$$|f(z)|\leq M \prod_{i=1}^n \left|\frac{z-a_k}{\bar{a_k}z-1}\right|\quad \forall n\in \mathbb{N}$$
It is not exactly clear how we can use $\sum(1-|a|_k)=\infty$ in our favor to make this upper bound go to zero. We may assume only finitely $|a_k|\leq \frac{1}{2}$ so we also know $\sum |a_k|=\infty$, but I am not sure if this helps.
EDIT: Geetha's comment sheds much light in this question. Assume by way of contradiction $f$ is not identically equal to zero and $|f(0)|\not=0$. This is untenable with Jensen's Theorem as may be seen  here. So $f$ is identically equal to zero or $f(0)=0$. Is there any counterexample of  $|f(0)|=0$ and $f$ non identically zero? Or does the problem still hold true?

This is  proved in Rudin's RCA. In the edition I have it is Theorem 15.23.

@geetha290krm, thank you so much, I have writen about Rudin's appproach but I think we must assume $|f(0)|\not=0$: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4910992/1015934 . I wonder if when $f(0)=0$ there are counterexamples...

If $f(0)=0$ with order $n$, consider $g(z):=f(z)/z^n$. Then $g$ is still bounded in the unit disk, because $g$ is bounded for $|z|\leq 1/2$, and for $1/2<|z|<1$ one has $|g(z)|\leq 2^n|f(z)|$. And $g$ has (aside from $0$) the same zeroes as does $f$, so simply apply the statement to $g$ instead of $f$.

@Schlitzer, that really finishes things off. I am always amazed by the sheer power of thought of the MSE community. I was a bit discouraged to think about $f(0)=0$, because Jensen seems hard and I thought it would be harder.  If you want to write your comment as an answer, feel free to do it.

I write what has already been stated in the comments to take this out of the unanswered list of questions:
If $f^{(k)}(0)=0$ for every $k$ then $f\equiv 0$, so we need only prove a zero of order $n$ leads to a contradiction.
In this case, $f(z)=z^nh(z)$ such that $h$ is analytic and non-zero at the origin. Jensen's Theorem teaches us that the mean value of $\log|f|$ on the border is $\log|f(0)|$ perturbed by points which bring the value of $\log(|f(0)|)$ to be smaller. This perturbation is more severe when we are close to $0$. Explicitly:
$$\log|h(0)|=\sum_{z_k\in D[0,r]}\log\left|\frac{z_k}{r}\right|+\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\log(|h(re^{i\theta}|)d\theta $$
Whenever we choose $r>0$ such that $h$ fails to be zero in $\partial D[0,r]$. It is possible to find such a value of $r$, otherwise there would be an infinite number of zeros (at least one such zero for every $1-2 \varepsilon \leq \tilde{r}\leq 1-\varepsilon$) in a closed disk $D[0,1-\varepsilon]$ and the identity theorem would imply $h\equiv 0$. So, we may take $r>1-2\varepsilon$ such that Jensen's formula holds true.
It is also clear that $h$ is bounded in $D[0,1/2]$ because of it being analytic there. It also follows that when $|z|\geq 1/2$, then $|h(z)|=|z^{-n}f(z)|\leq 2^n B$, where $B$ is a bound for $|f(z)|$. Defining $M=\max\{2^n B,\sup_{B[0,1/2]} |h(z)|\}$ implies that $|h(z)|\leq M$ and:
$$\log\left(|h(0)\prod_{k=1}^n \left| \frac{r}{z_k}\right|\right)\leq \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\log Md\theta$$
Taking the exponential and rearranging implies that:
$$\prod_{k=1}^{n} \left| \frac{z_k}{r}\right|\geq \frac{ |h(0)|}{M}>0 $$
The lefthandside is independent of $r$  ($M$ is any upper bound for $|h(z)|$ in the unit disk) which in turn implies (taking the limit as $r\rightarrow 1$ and using convexity of the exponential) that:
$$\prod_{i=1}^n e^{|z_k|-1}\geq \prod_{k=1}^{n} \left| z_k\right|\geq \frac{ |h(0)|}{M}>0$$
These are all of the zeros in $B[0,r]$ where $r\geq 1-2\varepsilon$. Hence, we may take $r$ sufficently close to one, such that $a_k$ for $k=1,...,N$ is among the $z_k$. Of course this implies that:
$$ e^{-\sum_{k=1}^N (1-|a_k|)}\geq e^{-\sum_{k=1}^n(1-|z_k|)}\geq \prod_{k=1}^{n} \left| z_k\right|\geq \frac{ |h(0)|}{M}>0$$
but $\sum_{k=1}^N (1-|a_k|)$ may be taken arbitrarily large by our hypothesis that the series diverges. Which in turn implies that $e^{-\sum_{k=1}^N (1-|a_k|)}$ is arbitrarily small. This is clearly a contradiction.

That $f$ is non-constant is ruled out by $\sum_k(1-\mid a_k\mid)=\infty. $
This rules it out.

Not quite. Jensen rules it out when $f(0)\not=0$.

@Kadmos I stand corrected.

Now I agree. :)
